# Import "ThisWorkbook" macro to another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, import, vbe

I need VBA code to import a procedure into `ThisWorkbook` scope within another workbook.

I have code to import a module into another workbook, but how to import this procedure into `ThisWorkbook` scope instead of into a module scope?

```
Sub TransferModule()
    Const modul As String = "Misc"
    Const tempfile As String = "/Users/Roman/Desktop/temp.bas"

    Dim WBK As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next

    Set WBK = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(modul).Export tempfile

    WBK.VBProject.VBComponents.Import tempfile

    Kill tempfile
End Sub
```

This takes module `Misc` from "This" workbook, exports it to `temp.bas` and then import it to another workbook. However I need it to import not into a module, but into `ThisWorkbook` scope. It's a `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than creating the new workbook with:

```
Set WBK = Workbooks.Add
```

consider using something like:

```
Sub lkjhgf()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ("C:\Users\Garys\Desktop\new.xlsm")
End Sub
```

The newly created workbook will have all the `ThisWorkbook` code that the original has.

*(Of course, you may have more clean-up to do to remove stuff you don't need copied.)*

**EDIT#1:**

See Vogelaar's answer here:

[Loading a subroutine into "ThisWorkbook" using VBA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b823faa5-a432-4435-84cd-a04eadcbd1f5/loading-a-subroutine-into-thisworkbook-using-vba?forum=exceldev)

Comment: Thank you, however I have macro that copy SheetA from Primary Workbook, to newWorkbook and in this newWorkbook I need to add Private Sub to "ThisWorkbook" if its possible. This PrivateSub I dont really need to have in Primary Workbook.